# Redirect To Another Page Information

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect

How to redirect to another page and take the information from the previous page ? I need this for one task. The task is:

*By using a GridView display the names of all employees from Northwind database as hyperlinks. All links should redirect to another page where details about the employee are displayed in a DetailsView. Add a back button to return back to the previous page.*

I am stucked here:

*All links should redirect to another page where details about the employee are displayed in a DetailsView.*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the hyperlinkfield for the GridView, which can define querystring parameters and bind them from the database.  Check out [this tutorial](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=8093456).

An example taken from the site:

```
<asp:HyperLinkField 
      DataTextField="UnitPrice" 
      DataTextFormatString="GBP {0}" 
      DataNavigateUrlFields="ProductID" HeaderText="Unit Price"
      DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID={0}"   />
```

Comment: What is the function of DataNavigateUrlFormatString="ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID={0}"  and what this ProductDetails.aspx?ProductID={0} exactly mean ?

Comment: @TheChampp You actually send with the URL a parameter that declare the id of your data that you going to display on the next page. On the next page you read your details base on this id. Is very basic, very simple.

Comment: hmm... I think that this is what I was searching for

Comment: Yes it replaces the {0} with the data fields, and you can pass as many parameters as you want; at binding time, the field values defined in the property DataNavigateUrlFields are injected into these placeholders, which can be {0}, {1}, etc.  Just make sure the ordering matches.